# java date format incompatible with xquery xs:date format, how to fix?

Tags: java, date, time, xquery

In java, when using SimpleDateFormat with the pattern:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ
```

the date is outputted as:

```
"2002-02-01T18:18:42.703-0700"
```

In xquery, when using the xs:dateTime function, it gives the error:

```
"Invalid lexical value [err:FORG0001]"
```

with the above date. In order for xquery to parse properly, the date needs to look like:

```
"2002-02-01T18:18:42.703-07:00" - node the ':' 3rd position from end of string
```

which is based on the ISO 8601, whereas Java date is based on the RFC 822 standard.

I would like to be able to easily specify the timezone in Java so that it will output the way that xquery wants.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

OK, the linked to forum post DID help, thank you. I did however find a simpler solution, which I include below:

1) Use Apache commons.lang java library
2) Use the following java code:

```java
//NOTE: ZZ on end is not compatible with jdk, but allows for formatting  
//dates like so (note the : 3rd from last spot, which is iso8601 standard):  
//date=2008-10-03T10:29:40.046-04:00  
private static final String DATE_FORMAT_8601 = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ";  
DateFormatUtils.format(new Date(), DATE_FORMAT_8601)
```

Comment: I'm happy you solved your own problem, I didn't know the commons library also contained a date formatter.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I did run into a problem - it doesn't appear to me (and I could be wrong) that there was any way to convert from and ISO string that DateUtils (from apache commons lang) creates, back to a date!
ie. apache commons will format it the way I would like, but not convert it back to a date again

So, I switched to JodaTime, and its much easier since its based on ISO8601 - here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date date = new Date();  
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);  
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();  
    String dateString = fmt.print(dateTime);  
    System.out.println("dateString=" + dateString);  
    DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime(dateString);  
    System.out.println("converted date=" + dt.toDate());  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Great find regarding commons.lang.java!  You can even save yourself from creating your own format string by doing the following:

```
DateFormatUtils.ISO_DATETIME_TIME_ZONE_FORMAT.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static public String formatISO8601(Calendar cal) {
MessageFormat format = new MessageFormat("{0,time}{1,number,+00;-00}:{2,number,00}");

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
df.setTimeZone(cal.getTimeZone());
format.setFormat(0, df);

long zoneOff = cal.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) + cal.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET) / 60000L;
int zoneHrs = (int) (zoneOff / 60L);
int zoneMins = (int) (zoneOff % 60L);
if (zoneMins < 0)
    zoneMins = -zoneMins;

return (format.format(new Object[] { cal.getTime(), new Integer(zoneHrs), new Integer(zoneMins) }));
}
```

Comment: This response seems to be accurate, but it also seems to be a copy of 'the answer' at the forum post that Jasper pointed to, without credit being given.  If you crib code, give credit!  And if you used someone else's answer to get there, give them credit too.