# Java - Convert string conforming to xs:date format into Oracle timestamp format

Tags: java, xml, oracle, datetime

Hello and thanks for reading.

I am presently faced with the challenge of converting a string representing a date/time in the xs:date format, into an Oracle timestamp.

The string I start out with looks like - "2011-07-12T16:20:02-04:00"

I need the timezone offset to be included in my Oracle timestamp. After the conversion process has taken place, I should end up with a timestamp that looks like -

"2011-07-12 12:20:02.0000"

Note that in the above example the timezone offset has been factored into the timestamp.

Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this? I've tried using a SimpleDateFormat object to first create a java.util.Date object from the string, and then converting that to a java.sql.Timestamp object. The problem here is that the timezone isn't factored in, and I think java.util.Date objects ignore timezone offsets regardless.

Hope someone can help me out here...

Edit : Solved - Here's the code I ended up using -

```
Calendar Cal = DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("2011-07-12T16:20:02+02:00");
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        System.out.println(df.format(Cal.getTime()));
```

Thanks again for reading,

Zachary Carter

Comment: See the attached link, it might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166600/java-date-format-incompatible-with-xquery-xsdate-format-how-to-fix

Comment: Thanks for the reply Perception. Unfortunately I cannot rely on any external Java libraries such as the Apache commons library. I need to use standard java libraries to perform this conversion if possible.

Comment: indeed knowing that `Calendar.getTime()` returns a `Date` object is the key here. Did not know this either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateFormats have timezones.  you basically need to configure a `SimpleDateFormat` with the correct format to parse the input timestamp (see note below).  technically, it includes the timezone info, so it won't matter what TimeZone you configure on the input formatter (you could use "GMT" just to be safe).  then, it looks like you want to output the timestamp using the GMT timezone (e.g. no timezone offset), so you could create another SimpleDateFormat with the output format you want, configured with the "GMT" TimeZone.

SimpleDateFormat may not be able to handle the xsd input format, so you can use the jaxb utils to handle that for you, see: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseDateTime(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

The SimpleDateFormat takes into account the timezone, if you use the proper format. Try to run this code and see the result:

```
    String s = "2011-07-12T16:20:02-0400";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    System.out.println(sdf.format(sdf.parse(s)));
```

Just be sure to convert -04:00 to -0400.

Comment: That SimpleDateFormat won't accept some valid XML dateTime values like those with timezone "Z"